# How to reference a Excel cell in the same row by letter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example of data:

[image]

I have a IF function in Excel that I would like to work dynamically but am not sure how to reference another cell by letter in the same row.

This statement is in E4(Excel Function):

```
IF(C4=Drake, "True", "False")
```

But I would like to use this statement in all rows in E so instead of C4 I need 'Cx' so the function would work in E5 too.

Comment: put the formula in E4, then just copy/drag it down.  Excel will change the row automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel references are treated as relative by default when you copy/pate or fill, so if you copy that formula from cell E4 to cell E5, the formula will be updated to

```
IF(C5=Drake, "True", "False")
```

If you don't *want* the formula to be relative, then prepend the row or column (or both) with a `$`.

For example, if your formula was

```
IF(C$4=Drake, "True", "False")
```

and you copied it from E4 to E5, the formula would stay

```
IF(C$4=Drake, "True", "False")
```

but if you copied it from E4 to F4, it would change to

```
IF(D$4=Drake, "True", "False")
```

Since the row is anchored but the column is not.

Answer (score -2):

```
=IF(OFFSET($E4,0,-2) = "Drake",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Then Fill Down.

HTH

Comment: Why `OFFSET($E4,0,-2)`? Why not just `$C4`?

Comment: Poor reading of problem and brain fart...LOL!